# Offer curves for giffen good

Tags: microeconomics, demand, giffen-goods

I learnt that giffen good doesn't satisfy the law of demand, but can we draw an offer curve to represent giffen good?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, both for a price and an income offer curve. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Also, you have a lot of [answered questions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/31619/shane-murphy?tab=questions); consider accepting some answers.

Comment: @Giskard-How would it look like? Any reference points? The internet is filled with interior and normal, haven't encountered any example highlighting the case of giffen good.

PS I just accepted some of the answers.

Comment: How would *what* look like? Price offer curve or income offer curve? And will you be satisfied with just a graph?

Comment: Price offer curve.. a graph should be fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a graph of the price offer curve of good $y$ when income is $48$ units, $p_x = 8$ and the utility function is
$$
U(x,y) = \min\left(2x+2y,x+10\right).
$$
(Based on "[Simple Utility Functions with Giffen Demand](https://web.econ.ku.dk/sorensen/papers/giffen.pdf)" by Sørensen). 
Good $y$ exhibits Giffen behavior when $0 < p_y < 8$.

[image]

A gif of the optimal choice changing as $p_y$ changes is presented below (budget set is grey, indifference curve and optimal bundle are green, income-offer curve is orange dashed line):

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I'll read your link to understand more.